# Mobile WebView is possible to implement Forge Disconnected WorkFlow

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

Thanks for your reply on disconnected workflows in mobile.

Disconnected workflow works in web browser in Mobile nice as you said ,but while using  web view in Mobile it is  possible cache.

My requirement is only one time  user need to download the  design to view the downloaded design at offline viewer when he wants or  when he don’t have internet signal he can able to view the  pervious downloaded design.

For the above requirement we can achieve from Disconnected workflows? Or any other suggestion to mobile offline viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "disconnected workflow" approach (using Service Workers and Cache API; see the [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows), [sample code](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-disconnected), or the [live demo](https://forge-disconnected.autodesk.io/)) supports this workflow. In the sample application you can cache a model by clicking the star icon next to it, and after the model has been cached, you can access it any time, even when disconnected from the internet.

Downloading the viewable files (SVF) from Forge and serving them yourself is not officially supported. The only exception is when customers are **not allowed** to store their data in the cloud, for example, due to government regulations. In that case we encourage you to talk to us (`forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`), and we'll see what we could do.